# Does the AWS SDK for NodeJS update the token from AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE in EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a simple application running in EKS/Kubernetes using a service account, that service account uses the IAM Role `Role_A`

Within the application container is possible to see the `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE` and `AWS_ROLE_ARN` environment variables (via `env | grep 'AWS'`)

Getting the content of the `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE`, I got a JWT with `exp` set to 24h from the `iss`.

With this context, my application uses this token to assume a role that has access to `S3` resources.

My application has this piece of code:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {Bucket: 'some-bucket', Key: 'some-file'}
const response = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
const fileContent = response.Body.toString('utf-8');
```

My question is: does the call `new AWS.S3()` deal with the token `exp` being used to assume the role? or it will receive a `403` error when the time is over?